# Google Script Pulling Data from URL & Randomly Missing Data Values on an Iteration

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, iteration

I'm pulling car dimensions from a generated URL column in google sheets. Here's an example of a sheet I'm working with:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e34rPOnzcCVVOBpbsq7R7Czoxli5Ryryh-UotQkfwHI/edit?usp=sharing

I have a function that fetches all the values in the Generated URL column. For each URL value, we fetch the HTML code from the site and scrape these values:

- Rear Head Room
- Rear Shoulder Room
- Cargo Capacity, All Seats in Place
- Max. Cargo Capacity

After running the complete code, the returned car dimension values are never static. The values will be pushed onto the google sheet correct sometimes but other times, I get my "no data" value.

I've used an if/else loop with isNaN to check if the value is a number before pushing it to the sheet. The else sets the value equal to "no data", which is sometimes set even when there is correct data on the link.

```
function getData(url, i, skip) {

  var temp = i;
  var tempurl = url;
  var options = {
    method : "GET",
    muteHttpExceptions : true
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var content = response.getContentText();

  var start1 = 'Rear head room</th><td class="px-1 px-lg-0_75 px-xl-1 py-0_5">';
  var end1 = 'in.</td>';
  var start2 = 'Rear shoulder room</th><td class="px-1 px-lg-0_75 px-xl-1 py-0_5">';
  var end2 = 'in.</td>';
  var start3 = 'Cargo capacity, all seats in place</th><td class="px-1 px-lg-0_75 px-xl-1 py-0_5">';
  var end3 = 'cu.ft.</td>';
  var start4 = 'Maximum cargo capacity</th><td class="px-1 px-lg-0_75 px-xl-1 py-0_5">';
  var end4 = 'cu.ft.</td>';

  //var dataa;
  var cut1 = content.indexOf(start1);
  var cut2 = content.indexOf(start2);
  var cut3 = content.indexOf(start3);
  var cut4 = content.indexOf(start4);
  Logger.log(cut1);
  Logger.log(cut2);

  var finish1 = content.indexOf(end1, cut1);
  var finish2 = content.indexOf(end2, cut2);
  var finish3 = content.indexOf(end3, cut3);
  var finish4 = content.indexOf(end4, cut4);
  Logger.log(finish1);
  Logger.log(finish2);

  var data1 = content.substring(cut1, finish1);
  var data2 = content.substring(cut2, finish2);
  var data3 = content.substring(cut3, finish3);
  var data4 = content.substring(cut4, finish4);
  Logger.log(data1);


  var value1 = data1.substring(62, 66);
  var value2 = data2.substring(66, 70);
  var value3 = data3.substring(82, 86);
  var value4 = data4.substring(70, 75);

  var comp1 = isNaN(value1);
  var comp2 = isNaN(value2);
  var comp3 = isNaN(value3);
  var comp4 = isNaN(value4);

  var comp = new Array;
  comp.push(comp1);
  comp.push(comp2);
  comp.push(comp3);
  comp.push(comp4);

  var checktest1 = 'n" c';
  var checktest2 = 'lass';
  var checktest3 = '  <m';
  var checktest4 = '="">';

  if (skip > 2) {
    var x = 0;
    while (x <= 3) {
      if (comp[x] == true) {
        switch(x) {
          case 0:
            value1 = "No Data";
            break;
          case 1:
            value2 = "No Data";
            break;
          case 2:
            value3 = "No Data";
            break;
          case 3:
            value4 = "No Data";
        }
        x++;
      }
      else {
        x++;
      }
    }
    setData(value1, value2, value3, value4, temp);
  }
  else if (value1 === checktest1 || value2 === checktest2 || value3 === checktest3 || value4 === checktest4) {
    var dataa = content;
    skip++;
    delete content;
    getData(tempurl, temp, skip); 
  }

  else {
    setData(value1, value2, value3, value4, temp);
  }

}


function setData(value1, value2, value3, value4, temp) {

  var index = temp - 2;
  var x = 0;
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss1.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange(2, 10);

  var cell1 = value1;
  var cell2 = value2;
  var cell3 = value3;
  var cell4 = value4;

  var isEmp = new Array;
  isEmp.push(value1);
  isEmp.push(value2);
  isEmp.push(value3);
  isEmp.push(value4);
  var coltest = '="">';

  while (x <= 3) {   
    if (isEmp[x] === '' || isEmp[x] === coltest) {
      switch(x) {
        case 0:
          value1 = "No Data";
          break;
        case 1:
          value2 = "No Data";
          break;
        case 2:
          value3 = "No Data";
          break;
        case 3:
          value4 = "No Data";
        }
      x++;
    }
    else {
      x++;

    }
  }

  cell.offset(index, 0).setValue(cell1);
  cell.offset(index, 1).setValue(cell2);
  cell.offset(index, 2).setValue(cell3);
  cell.offset(index, 3).setValue(cell4);

}
```

Out of the 148 iterations, my program fails to get roughly 20-25 random rows worth of data. The random wrong rows are never the same but do contain the correct values but were somehow randomly missed.

Comment: Would you please run the code, then copy/paste the Execution transcript (from the script editor), and edit your question to include the Execution transcript. I am also running your code off-line and will respond in due course.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/12r8IwEjrjaqXhSruvTQ-W1HiRCErLxSwXej17FuSdCA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: My test populated the entire 148 rows - there are some glitches here and there (2 x bits of html, 7x #ERROR!, and about 4 random empty cells). I've inexplicably got an error message "Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch." (refers to  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); in `getData`). I think it is distorted by `getStatusCode` which also uses UrlFetchApp; probably better to to copy/paste special, values for the formula in Column P, otherwise it just uses quote unnecessarily. (Or run a script and drop the result as a value). Your Execution transcript is important.

Comment: What results did you get from that run? The transcript says "Execution succeeded", though it took 3+ minutes.

Comment: My "inexplicable error" is not so inexplicable; I duplicated several pages - this combined with constant recalculations tipped the balance. You might wish to look at converting `getStatusCode` to a script that inserts a value in a cell rather than acting as a custom formula.

Comment: My runs always populate the entire 148 rows and takes usually 3 minutes. I took out the getStatusCode and ran but still got the same random error results.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post so that others can better help you. It would especially help if you would narrow down the issue to the portion that actually causes your data to be wrong (before the fetch, after the fetch, before insertion, etc.; as specific as possible). Please do not post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems being generated by the script:

1. BLANK FIELDS

   - BMW X5 - 2 x blank fields: Cargo Capacity, All Seats in Place (cu ft) & Maximum Cargo Capacity (cu ft). The website does not quote values for these fields.
2. HTML IN A FIELD

   - SUZUKI SX4 and MERCEDES-BENZ    GLS-CLASS - 1 field: Cargo Capacity, All Seats in Place (cu ft). The website does not provide data for this field; and the HTML returned "
3. `#ERROR!`

   - FORD ECOSPORT, FORD EDGE, GMC YUKON DENALI, HONDA HR-V, JEEP COMPASS, LINCOLN MKX, LINCOLN MKT (7 vehicles) - Maximum Cargo Capacity (cu ft)"; the returned value (`="">`) is tested by the code but is not corrected due to a flaw.

The code uses a "SWITCH" method in two functions to adjust for the various problems mentioned above. However the code is flawed in how this is managed.

A simplified approach is to assign "No Data" values immediately after the `isNaN()` code in `getDATA`. Such as:

---

```
    if(comp1 === true){
        //Logger.log("getData comp adjust - comp1 = true");
        var value1 = "No Data";
    }
    if(comp2 === true){
        //Logger.log("getData comp adjust - comp2 = true");
        var value2 = "No Data";
    }
    if(comp3 === true){
        //Logger.log("getData comp adjust - comp3 = true");
        var value3 = "No Data";
    }
    if(comp4 === true){
        //Logger.log("getData comp adjust - comp4 = true");
        var value4 = "No Data";
    }
```

---

With this addition, the switch statements and two of the "else" options in `getdata` are unnecessary, and the switch in `setdata` is also unnecessary. The switch in setdata is flawed anyway since it reassigns "value" amounts, but doesn't update those values before the `setValues` statement.